# Display a viewcontroller in Xcode/swift using if else for login

Tags: swift, if-statement, authentication, swift4, viewcontroller

I want a to have a conditional if statement to be run when the button is clicked. Basically, it will be if CodigoError is different from 0000 i want to stay in the same view controller which is the login, but if it's correct i want to display the other view controller

Please help i've been searching everywhere, 
sorry for my english i'm peruvian

```
if CodigoError != "0000" {

} else {
    self.MessageAlert(userMessage:("Bienvenido(a) " + objReturn.ODNOMBRE! + " " + objReturn.ODAPEMA! + " " + objReturn.ODAPEPA!),title:"Banca Móvil")

    //  self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender:self)
    //  self.navigateFirstViewController()
}
```

Comment: You are on a pretty good way using `performSegue(withIdentifier: sender:)`. You just need to check that there is a Storyboard Segue connected to your "FirstViewController" and that the identifier inside your Storyboard equals the one inside your `performSegue` function.

Comment: The section `"0000: { }` would be not matching so stay on the screen.  The section `} else {  }` would mean it's a match and as @AndréKuhlmann stated you would use the `performSegue(withIdentifier: sender:)` to change view controllers.

Comment: so how can i do to stay on the same view controller?

Comment: If you want to stay you don't have to do anything. Just like in your code above. What you could use is `return` inside your `if CodigoError != "0000"` statement, but this is not really necessary.